# How to bind to CheckedProvider in guice?

Tags: java, guice

Guice provides a way to bind to provider:

```
    bind(A.class).toProvider(AProvider.class);
```

Although if my provider needs to throw an exception then it seems that CheckedProvider is a right base interface:

```
    public interface ConfigCheckedProvider<T> extends CheckedProvider<T> {
        T get() throws ConfigException;
    }

    public AProvider implements ConfigCheckedProvider<A> { ... }
```

But now some of my classes need instance of A to be injected. And this I can't change. But it looks like toProvider method doesn't accept CheckedProvider types.

How I can use providers based on CheckedProvider to **inject instances not providers**?

Comment: Wouldn't this defeat the purpose of the `@CheckedProvider`? How would injecting an instance throw an exception? I think if you want to inject instances you'll have to switch to an implementation of plain old `Provider` (and only throw runtime exceptions).

Comment: @CheckedProvider isn't applicable to providers which are classes. And plain old Provider doesn't allow exceptions throwing. The question: how to have provider in separate class (big initialization logic) and allow this provider to throw exceptions. But the final goal is not to inject provider, but to inject instance provided by provider.

Comment: @vladimir, you cannot do that. Checked providers were made exactly for disallowing injection of objects directly because their creation may fail, and this failure must be handled by the program code. If you do not want to handle creation failure then you may use plain providers and wrap all checked exceptions in `get()` in some runtime exception.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev please post your comment as an answer. Seems to be an answer. However I have to say that @ Provides and @ CheckedProvides both allow to throw exception from annotated methods. So I don't fully see the point of having this protection. At least this protection doesn't seem to be consistent with annotated providers.

Comment: @vladimir, that is because it is not possible to check in compile time which exceptions are declared on a method using annotations. It is possible to do only via inheritance (and that is also a part of reason why `@CheckedProvides` needs an interface to be specified). I believe that `@Provides` methods handle declared checked exceptions exactly as unchecked ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you requested, I'm posting my comment as an answer.

---

If you have a class `T` and a checked provider `TProvider extends CheckedProvider<T>`, you cannot inject just `T`:

```
@Inject
SomeClass(T t) {  // Won't work
    ...
}
```

as you would be able if you had used plain `Provider<T>`. This is done intentionally. Checked providers are needed when creation of an object may fail with a particular type of exception, and this failure must be handled by user code. Plain providers do not have such feature.

`Provider<T>` does not allow throwing checked exceptions from its `get()` method, and any unchecked exceptions it throws may be wrapped into a `ProvisionException`, so you cannot reliably catch your exception. Also, if you inject `T` directly and your provider's `get()` method fails, then you will get an error during the injection, which may lead to incomprehensible stacktraces (especially if you are not using `Injector`s directly) or even their absence.

Checked providers allow you to throw predeclared types of exceptions from your providers, and these exceptions are guaranteed to be passed as is to the code which calls `get()` on your checked provider. This way you can reliably catch them, but in return you lose an ability to inject objects which are created by the provider directly.

See [this manual](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ThrowingProviders) on throwing and checked providers for more background on what I just have written.

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that what I'm asked for is intentionally not provided in guice. However the one might write his own checked provider which will implement Provider and therefore usable in toProvider bindings.

For example I have provided in question the following Checked Provider might make sense:

```
public abstract class MyCheckedProvider<T, E extends Exception> 
                      implements Provider<T> {

    public abstract T getChecked() throws E;

    @Override
    public T get() {
        try {
            return getChecked();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ProvisionException("Checked provider threw exception", e );
        }
    }
}
```

With this MyProvider the AProvider might look like:

```
public class AProvider extends MyCheckedProvider<A, ConfigException> {
    @Override
    public A getChecked() throws ConfigException {
        ...
    }
}


bind(A.class).toProvider(AProvider.class);
```

All this works only if you want to throw ProvisionExceptions if something goes wrong in provider. For other logic MyProvider should obviously have other implmentation of get method...